# How to execute multiple SQL files in UNIX?

Tags: sql, shell, unix, oracle11g, sh

I have n .sql files for example 1.sql, 2.sl, 3.sql.... n.sql in a folder named sql_scripts. I want to execute all those files using a single shell script. Whats the easiest and the most preferred way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

```
cat 1.sql 2.sql 3.sql ... n.sql |sqlplus username/password@sid
```

Or

```
cat *.sql|sqlplus username/password@sid
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the files, executing each one in turn:

```bash
for file in /home/user/sql_scripts/*.sql; do
    echo "Executing $f.."
    sqlplus user/pass @"$f"
done
```

You can run a file in SQLPlus by using the `@filename.sql` notation.

Answer (score 0):

as explained above by Josh,

using @sqlscript.sql in sqlplus is the best way but this technique might not work in all databases, instead you can modify your script like,

```
su - <db user>
connect to database <your db name >
```

(this again varies according to your db i.e.
in db2  it is like db2 connect to , in oracle connect to  etc)

```
for file in /home/user/sql_scripts/*.sql; do
    echo "Executing $f.."
    db2 -tvf "$f" <db2>
    @"$f"         <oracle/sqlplus etc>   
done
```

modify above script as per your db and requirements.